# Transfer Walking Dead 2 Save from XBox 360 to XBox One

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, the-walking-dead-season-two

I bought Walking Dead 2 for XBox One, but I previously played Walking Dead 1 on XBox 360.

Is there any way to link the XBox 360 to the XBox One, so we can continue the story where we left off? Or should I just buy the game for the XBox 360?

Comment: You mean you want to transfer the save game from the Xbox 360 version to the Xbox One version?

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/51632/the-walking-dead-unofficial-faq-please-read-before-posting) you can transfer your S1 savegame to the cloud, perhaps this function is available in S2 as well, and can be used to transfer between consoles?

Comment: Yes, transfer the game from the 360 to the 1.

Answer (score 4):

The saves will not transfer.  According to [this](https://www.telltalegames.com/support/discussion/86231/xbox-360-saves-to-xbox-one) forum post, the moderator confirmed that save games cannot be transferred between consoles.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to send your save data onto a USB device in your XBox 360, but I think the XBox One has different save patterns for different games I own a XBox 360 but not XBox one so I can't fully say I know. So do it at your own risk.